# variables equal with doublemetaphone on pyspark

Tags: pyspark, boolean, metaphone

I want to use the fonction **"doublemetaphone"** on my data set on **pyspark**. 
The expectation result is a boolean: TRUE or FALSE. 
But *@udf("bool")* doesn't work, is there another way?

````
from metaphone import doublemetaphone

@udf("bool") 
def udf_doublemetaphone(a,b):
  return doublemetaphone(a)== doublemetaphone(b)

data_set_doublemetaphone = (data_set.withColumn("doublemetaphone", 
                                                   udf_doublemetaphone(col("A"),col("B")))) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I have find! 
This is **@udf(BooleanType())** 
So you can use like this:
rom metaphone import doublemetaphone

````
@udf(BooleanType()) 
def udf_doublemetaphone(a,b):
 return doublemetaphone(a)== doublemetaphone(b)

data_set_doublemetaphone = (data_set.withColumn("doublemetaphone", 
                                                  udf_doublemetaphone(col("A"),col("B")))) ```
````